# Why in the date field appears "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the format in datetime picker like "format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" and to store the date in the database is used the format "            `'start_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->start_date),`
".

In the conference details page I want to show the stored date in db. But like below in the date field appears "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" instead of appear the date. Do you know why?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="start_date">Start date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
                   name="start_date" value="{{!empty($conference->start_date) ? $conference->start_date->formatLocalized('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii'): ''}}
                    "
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="end_date">End date
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' class="form-control"
                   value=" {{!empty($conference->end_date) ? $conference->end_date->formatLocalized('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii'): ''}}
                           " name="end_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[formatLocalized()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) uses [strrftime()](http://www.php.net/strftime) under the hood and is used for formatting local time/date according to locale settings so I don't think that's the method you're wanting to use.

Also, the format you're passing to the method is not correct for use with PHP. To format the date correctly with php you should look at [the docs for php date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

In you blade file change:

```
$conference-start_date->formatLocalized('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii')
```

to:

```
$conference-start_date->format('d F Y - H:i')
```

Do the same for the `end_date` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
                   name="start_date" value="{{!empty($conference->start_date) ? $conference->start_date->formatLocalized('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii'): ''}}
                    "
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
```

Instead of above code replace it with below,

```
<input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
                   name="start_date" value="{{!empty($conference->start_date) ? $conference->start_date->format('d/m/Y')): ''}}
                    "
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
```

You were messing in format conversion while printing

```
$conference->start_date->formatLocalized('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii')
```

As you have used carbon for date conversion you can also use it while printing

```
$conference->start_date->format('d/m/Y')
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that the format is not like "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii".